# Scaling weapon or elemental weapon?

Tags: dark-souls

In my experience I find that opponents with elemental weapons fares way better towards me (I'm lvl 61, using a +5 Channeler's trident with 50 INT) than those that don't.

Is it better to have a scaling B, A or S rank weapon and pump levels into needed stat or have an elemental (fire or elemental) weapon when doing pvp?

How about Chaos weapons, is it worth farming up to 99 humanity?

Comment: Chaos weapons don't scale up to 99, just to 10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "it depends".

The first thing to consider is that elemental weapons don't scale, but do have high base damage due to their elemental attack (depending on the enemy). Due to this elemental weapons, and weapons with a high base damage in general, are preferable in the early portions of the game to weapons with high scaling but low base damage. This is because early in the game your stats are not high enough to give you a sizeable scaling bonus. With that said however, your damage with a scaling weapon will eventually greatly out weigh the damage you do with elemental weapons in the end, and is therefore preferable in most situations.

There is one last thing to consider though, which is all enemies have different resistance to elemental and physical attacks. Some enemies are really weak against lightning, and others take almost no damage from it. Whereas others will take a bunch of damage from physical attacks, whereas others will only take a small amount of damage. Due to this, regardless of your level, you will always find enemies where a weapon with high elemental damage will be preferable, but as a general rule of thumb, you should be focusing on using weapons with high stat scaling, and using elemental damages as back-up weapons.

Comment: A follow up question would've been: How can I calculate the damage output for each scaling level (B, A or S) ?